# В линуксе при запуске python скрипта, терминал выводит \n где должен быть переход строки

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, kali-linux

Код программы:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess

ifconfig_result = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig", "eth0"])
print(ifconfig_result)
```

[image: Вывод программы]

┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/PycharmProjects/Hello]
└─$ python error.py
b'eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500\n        inet6 fe80::221:32ff:fe44:5566  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20\n        ether 00:22:33:44:55:66  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)\n        RX packets 30  bytes 13460 (13.1 KiB)\n        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0\n        TX packets 811  bytes 80792 (78.8 KiB)\n        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0\n\n'

Не знаю даже что пробовать. В гугле нужной информации не нашёл

Comment: Ну так сам print его и добавил. Он так всегда делает, если явно не попросить.

Comment: Это нормально, он так и работает - хотите делайте `splitlines()` на результате и получайте список.

Answer (score 1):

`ifconfig_result` — это байтовый массив ([`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray)). На это указывает, в частности, литера `b` перед выводом.

Чтобы нормально вывести его в терминал нужно конвертировать его в строку с помощью `decode()`. На большинстве систем с локалью utf-8 или если массив содержит только latin1-символы будет достаточно:

```
print(ifconfig_result.decode())
```

Более переносимым вариантом будет являться:

```
import sys
print(ifconfig_result.decode(sys.getdefaultencoding())
```